# How to set, for each raster band, the min and max color values (using GDAL)

Tags: c++, colors, raster, grayscale, gdal

I successfully created a multiband raster image using GDAL in MSVS (C++), but I do not know how to setup (for each band) the min and max color scale in order I could open the image in my QGIS application and the image loads with the proper color scale. I also would like to setup the contrast to extend from min to max.

Anybody have an idea how to code it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Compute the statistics for each raster band; see 
[CPLErr GDALRasterBand::ComputeStatistics](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723222834/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALRasterBand.html#a48883c1dae195b21b37b51b10e910f9b) for more info.